# Existence of PMF on positive integers such that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{P(x+1)}{P(x) \log(x)} >0$.

Tags: probability

I am looking for an example  of a probability mass function  on positive integers that satisfies the following limit:
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{P(x+1)}{P(x) \log(x)}=c,\label{*}\tag{*}
\end{align}
for some positive constant $c$.

**Precise questions:**   Does there exists a probability mass function on positive integers satisfying \eqref{*}?

I am inclined to think that no such distribution exists.

Comment: Is there some context to this question? Why is it that you are interested?

Comment: @Math1000  I am doing a proof by contradictions,  and I got to this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There does not exist such a distribution. If it did exist, there must exist $N\ge2$ large enough that

- $\dfrac {P(n+1)}{P(n)\log n} \ge \frac c2$ for $n\ge N$ (from definition of limit);
- $P(N) > 0$ (the given limit means that $P$ can't be finitely supported).

But then $P(N+k) \ge P(N)(\frac c2 \log N)^k$ for every $k\ge1$, which eventually contradicts $P(N+k) \le 1$.

Comment: nice +1.  this actually works for a very large class of functions $f$, not just $\log$.  i think any $f$ that tends to $\infty$ or just goes arbitrarily large infinitely often?

Comment: Quick question. The proof includes the case of $c=\infty$, right?

Comment: Yes and yes, the proof works with $\log$ replaced by any function that is eventually greater than $1+\delta$ for some fixed $\delta>0$; and if $c=\infty$, then you can use any positive real number in place of $\frac c2$.

Comment: One more question. What is it still true if we replace $\lim$ by $\limsup$? I just want to be safe for the cases when the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: No, there are definitely examples if lim is replaced by lim sup. For example, any distribution supported only on even integers has that property (with $c=\infty$), and hence so will infinitesimal perturbations if you don't want to allow $P(x)=0$.

Comment: Thanks. Final question, why is there no $k$ over $\frac{c}{2} P(N)$?

Comment: aha, because typo! well spotted